# Mobius camera interface in ROS

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to work with **mobius actioncam** and ROS on **nvidia tegra tk1**. I've tried both **uvc_camera** and **usb_cam** packages but without success. **uvc_camera** gives me this error: "I only handle discrete frame intervals" and **usb_cam** just dies.

Did anyone try mobius camera on **tk1**?

**Edit**: The behavior is the same on my computer. Is there even **mobius** driver for ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266945/mobius-camera-interface-in-ros/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 826 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:\

> Is there even mobius driver for ROS?

well, have you found anything?

More general though: can you open the camera in something like `cheese` or `guvcview`?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-07-21**:
I tried displaying camera output in vlc and it works just fine. I think I'll probably have to write my own interface to get it working with ROS...

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-07-21**:
Oh, didn't know that srry. I tried guvcview and it works. I will have a look at gscam then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I specifically asked about `guvcview` and `cheese` because they use the same `uvc` interface as `uvc_camera` and `libuvc_camera`. VLC could be using `v4l` or `v4l2`.

You could take a look at [gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-07-21**:
Gscam worked for me. Thank you gvdhoorn.